# SQL Impala reducing id by most frequent value

Tags: sql, group-by, frequency, impala, partition

Given a table like the following:

```
+--+------------------+-----------+
|id|     diagnosis_age|  diagnosis|
+--+------------------+-----------+
| 1|2.1843037179180302| 315.320000|
| 1|  2.80033330216659| 315.320000|
| 1|   2.8222365762732| 315.320000|
| 1|  5.64822705794013| 325.320000|
| 1| 5.686557787521759| 335.320000|
| 2|  5.70572315231258| 315.320000|
| 2| 5.724888517103389| 315.320000|
| 3| 5.744053881894209| 315.320000|
| 3|5.7604813374292005| 315.320000|
| 3|  5.77993740687426| 315.320000|
+--+------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to reduce each id to just one row by selecting the diagnosis and age with the most frequent diagnosis.

output would look like:

```
+--+------------------+-----------+
|id|     diagnosis_age|  diagnosis|
+--+------------------+-----------+
| 1|2.1843037179180302| 315.320000|
| 2|  5.70572315231258| 315.320000|
| 3| 5.744053881894209| 315.320000|
+--+------------------+-----------+
```

I've tried things like:

```
SELECT id, diagnosis, age,
COUNT(distinct diagnosis) OVER (partition by id)
FROM table
```

But am not really getting anything to work!

using the below code:

```
wc=Window().partitionBy("id", "diagnosis").orderBy("diagnosis_age")
wc2=Window().partitionBy("id")
ddfc.withColumn("count", F.count("diagnosis").over(wc))\
  .withColumn("max", F.max("count").over(wc2))\
  .filter("count=max")\
.groupBy("id").agg(F.first("diagnosis_age").alias("diagnosis_age"), F.first("diagnosis").alias("diagnosis"))\
  .orderBy("id")\
.groupBy("diagnosis")\
.count()\
.orderBy("count", ascending = False)\
.show(5)
```

I get:

```
+--------------+-----+
|diagnosis     |count|
+--------------+-----+
|         V20.2|22179|
|    382.900000|12985|
|    389.900000|11333|
|    381.810000| 7448|
|    493.900000| 3249|
+--------------+-----+
```

whereas your code (amended to group by diagnosis and get the 5 most frequent diagnosis) outputs:

```
+--------------+------+
|diagnosis     |count |
+--------------+------+
| 389.900000   |13268 | 
| 382.900000   | 7572 | 
| V20.2        | 6193 | 
| 381.810000   | 4735 | 
| V72.19       | 4115 | 
+--------------+------+
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't understand the results.  Why a/2, for instance?

Comment: . . You have no duplicates on age, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistics, this is the most common value and it is called the *mode*.

You can use aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select id, diagnosis, age
from (select id, diagnosis, min(age) as age, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, diagnosis
     ) da
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I ran your code last night and assumed it was working because each id was distinct. I could be wrong but doesn't where seqnum = 1 ensure that the count is always 1? I've amended the op to examples more like the data I'm working with. Basically, the results I obtained with your code didn't actually match those I obtained through rdd in pyspark (which I believe to be correct). I basically added GROUP BY diagnosis ORDER BY diagnosis_frequency DESC LIMIT 5; to your code and ended up with very different results. I'm not sure why this is?

Comment: @mad-a . . . Not at all.  I think the issue is "age".  I find your phrasing a bit unclear -- you seem to want the diagnosis that this most common for an `id`.  I'm not sure where `age` fits into this.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I made an assumption about age that I shouldn't have, your updated code does indeed do what I intended to explain. Sorry for the confusion.